# Random infinite loop in Tic Tac Toe

Tags: vb.net

So I've been trying to make a TicTacToe game for a programming class, and the teacher is useless. :l

When I run the program, 8 times out of 10; when I play and get the grid almost full, it freezes. It's semi-difficult to explain, and I'm really tired. I hope someone can help. :s

Code:

```
    Private Sub ChooseBox()
    Dim num As Integer
    Dim Random As New Random
    num = Random.Next(0, 10)

    If Grid_1.Text <> "" And Grid_2.Text <> "" And Grid_3.Text <> "" And Grid_4.Text <> "" And Grid_5.Text <> "" And Grid_6.Text <> "" And Grid_7.Text <> "" And Grid_8.Text <> "" And Grid_9.Text <> "" Then
        gStatus = "Tie"
        Me.Text = "Tic Tac Toe - Nobody won!"
    Else
        If num = 1 And Grid_1.Text = "" Then
            Grid_1.Text = compChar : turnIs = "Player"
        ElseIf num = 2 And Grid_2.Text = "" Then
            Grid_2.Text = compChar : turnIs = "Player"
        ElseIf num = 3 And Grid_3.Text = "" Then
            Grid_3.Text = compChar : turnIs = "Player"
        ElseIf num = 4 And Grid_4.Text = "" Then
            Grid_4.Text = compChar : turnIs = "Player"
        ElseIf num = 5 And Grid_5.Text = "" Then
            Grid_5.Text = compChar : turnIs = "Player"
        ElseIf num = 6 And Grid_6.Text = "" Then
            Grid_6.Text = compChar : turnIs = "Player"
        ElseIf num = 7 And Grid_7.Text = "" Then
            Grid_7.Text = compChar : turnIs = "Player"
        ElseIf num = 8 And Grid_7.Text = "" Then
            Grid_8.Text = compChar : turnIs = "Player"
        ElseIf num = 9 And Grid_9.Text = "" Then
            Grid_9.Text = compChar
        Else : ChooseBox()
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub CheckResult()

    'First Column is filled
    If Grid_1.Text = compChar And Grid_2.Text = compChar And Grid_3.Text = compChar Then
        gStatus = "Won"
        Me.Text = "Tic Tac Toe - Computer Wins!"
    ElseIf Grid_1.Text = playerChar And Grid_2.Text = playerChar And Grid_3.Text = playerChar Then
        gStatus = "Won"
        Me.Text = "Tic Tac Toe - Player Wins!"
    End If

    'Second Column is filled
    If Grid_4.Text = compChar And Grid_5.Text = compChar And Grid_6.Text = compChar Then
        gStatus = "Won"
        Me.Text = "Tic Tac Toe - Computer Wins!"
    ElseIf Grid_4.Text = playerChar And Grid_5.Text = playerChar And Grid_6.Text = playerChar Then
        gStatus = "Won"
        Me.Text = "Tic Tac Toe - Player Wins!"
    End If

    'Third Column is filled
    If Grid_7.Text = compChar And Grid_8.Text = compChar And Grid_9.Text = compChar Then
        gStatus = "Won"
        Me.Text = "Tic Tac Toe - Computer Wins!"
    ElseIf Grid_7.Text = playerChar And Grid_8.Text = playerChar And Grid_9.Text = playerChar Then
        gStatus = "Won"
        Me.Text = "Tic Tac Toe - Player Wins!"
    End If

    'First Row is filled
    If Grid_1.Text = compChar And Grid_4.Text = compChar And Grid_7.Text = compChar Then
        gStatus = "Won"
        Me.Text = "Tic Tac Toe - Computer Wins!"
    ElseIf Grid_1.Text = playerChar And Grid_4.Text = playerChar And Grid_7.Text = playerChar Then
        gStatus = "Won"
        Me.Text = "Tic Tac Toe - Player Wins!"
    End If

    'Second Row is filled
    If Grid_2.Text = compChar And Grid_5.Text = compChar And Grid_8.Text = compChar Then
        gStatus = "Won"
        Me.Text = "Tic Tac Toe - Computer Wins!"
    ElseIf Grid_2.Text = playerChar And Grid_5.Text = playerChar And Grid_8.Text = playerChar Then
        gStatus = "Won"
        Me.Text = "Tic Tac Toe - Player Wins!"
    End If

    'Third Row is filled
    If Grid_3.Text = compChar And Grid_6.Text = compChar And Grid_9.Text = compChar Then
        gStatus = "Won"
        Me.Text = "Tic Tac Toe - Computer Wins!"
    ElseIf Grid_3.Text = playerChar And Grid_6.Text = playerChar And Grid_9.Text = playerChar Then
        gStatus = "Won"
        Me.Text = "Tic Tac Toe - Player Wins!"
    End If

    'Diagonal Upwards is filled
    If Grid_1.Text = compChar And Grid_5.Text = compChar And Grid_9.Text = compChar Then
        gStatus = "Won"
        Me.Text = "Tic Tac Toe - Computer Wins!"
    ElseIf Grid_1.Text = playerChar And Grid_5.Text = playerChar And Grid_9.Text = playerChar Then
        gStatus = "Won"
        Me.Text = "Tic Tac Toe - Player Wins!"
    End If

    'Diagonal Downwards is filled
    If Grid_3.Text = compChar And Grid_5.Text = compChar And Grid_7.Text = compChar Then
        gStatus = "Won"
        Me.Text = "Tic Tac Toe - Computer Wins!"
    ElseIf Grid_3.Text = playerChar And Grid_5.Text = playerChar And Grid_7.Text = playerChar Then
        gStatus = "Won"
        Me.Text = "Tic Tac Toe - Player Wins!"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: ProTip: Always use `AndAlso` in conditionals, never `And`. The former shortcuts (the second part is not evaluated if the first part is `False`) so it's usually more convenient and also faster (especially if the terms are function calls). Same goes for `Or` and `OrElse`.

Comment: Can you show the rest of your program?

Comment: @msarchet The rest of the code is here: http://pastebin.com/RE8RWW5T

Comment: @minitech, Thanks! I'll keep this in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three problems I see:

```
num = Random.Next(0, 10)
```

Random.Next is lower-bound inclusive and upper-bound exclusive.  This means the computer can roll a 0 here.  This won't cause a loop, but it's slightly wasteful since you never accept a 0 in your conditionals.

```
ElseIf num = 9 And Grid_9.Text = "" Then
    Grid_9.Text = compChar
```

Here, your pattern doesn't include returning control to Player.  I expect the computer would get two turns in this scenario.

```
ElseIf num = 8 And Grid_7.Text = "" Then
    Grid_8.Text = compChar : turnIs = "Player"
```

Now this is the likely loop problem.  Notice when the computer rolls an 8 you're checking grid 7 for contents.  So if grid 8 is the last space, you will always fall through to another ChooseBox() call.  The loop never resolves.

Comment: Wow... I can't believe I missed that. >_<
Thanks for pointing that out to me!
Now I just need to manage to get more sleep before waking at 5:00 AM. -_-

Also, I haven't included all of the code, but I return control to the player in a different subroutine. :)

Also, So if I change the `(0, 10)` to `(1, 9)`, it will still do 1-9? I've tried this before and it never seemed to work.

Comment: I believe you want (1, 10).  The lower bound is included.  The upper bound is not.  This is how it works in C# anyway, the Intellisense should be able to confirm it for you in VB.

Answer (score 0):

You've set yourself up for a possible infinite choice situation. You would be better off using a list which contains the number of each of the cells:

```
Dim cells As New List(Of String)()
cells.Add("1")
cells.Add("2")
...
cells.Add("9")
```

Then as you use up a particular cell, remove it from the list.

```
ElseIf num = 5 And Grid_5.Text = "" Then
    Grid_5.Text = compChar
    turnIs = "Player"
    cells.RemoveAt(num - 1)  ' Remove the cell at the index in the List
ElseIf num = 6 And Grid_6.Text = "" Then
    ...
```

This will allow you to iterate down in with your choice of random:

```
Dim Random As New Random
num = Random.Next(0, cells.Count - 1)  ' This will only allow choices within range
```

That way, whenever the `ChooseBox()` method is called, you can be sure that whatever index is chosen at random is available. This might also reduce the need for the `Text = ""` check as well.

*Note: It's also a good idea for readability's sake to forget that the `:` character allows you to have multiple lines of code on a single line. Unless that line is a singular instruction or a conditional then instruction, it just ends up making the code bulky.*